# Node.js with simple redis application throwing 'unhandled error'

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I wanted to try out example application from http://expressjs.com/guide.html so I wrote the following :

```
var express = require('express')
var redis = require('redis')
var db = redis.createClient();
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  var ua = req.headers['user-agent'];
  db.zadd('online', Date.now(), ua, next);
});

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  var min = 60 * 1000;
  var ago = Date.now() - min;
  db.zrevrangebyscore('online', '+inf', ago, function(err, users){
    if (err) return next(err);
    req.online = users;
    next();
  });
});

app.get('/', function(req,res){
  res.send(req.online.length + ' users online');
});


app.listen(3000);
```

but after trying to launch it I get

```
events.js:71
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED
    at RedisClient.on_error (/home/USER/programming/nodejs/express1/node_modules/redis/index.js:148:24)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/USER/programming/nodejs/express1/node_modules/redis/index.js:83:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at Socket._destroy.self.errorEmitted (net.js:329:14)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

I use `node.js` 0.8.18 and following packages:

```
app@0.0.1 /home/USER/programming/nodejs/express1
├─┬ express@3.1.0
│ ├── buffer-crc32@0.1.1
│ ├── commander@0.6.1
│ ├─┬ connect@2.7.2
│ │ ├── bytes@0.1.0
│ │ ├── formidable@1.0.11
│ │ ├── pause@0.0.1
│ │ └── qs@0.5.1
│ ├── cookie@0.0.5
│ ├── cookie-signature@0.0.1
│ ├── debug@0.7.2
│ ├── fresh@0.1.0
│ ├── methods@0.0.1
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.3
│ ├── range-parser@0.0.4
│ └─┬ send@0.1.0
│   └── mime@1.2.6
└── redis@0.8.2
```

Comment: Is your local Redis installation properly configured and running on port 6379? `ECONNREFUSED` indicates the problem is with Redis, or a system port setting/firewall, not Node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the port of reddis. If correct, give a wildcard to that port in any firewall which might block it. Check whether something else is using that port. Check your connection settings.

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing but I ... did not have the redis running... Thanks a lot anyway :)

Comment: Sometimes I can answer my own questions right after I ask someone else who doesn't know the answer. If you ask yourself the right question, then you might help yourself in providing the answer.